# Errors while creating SAS hash join with complex comparisons from sql

Tags: sql, join, hash, sas

I am trying to write a SAS hash join from a proc sql.

The proc sql is like this:

```
    proc sql;
        create table output_table as
        select a.*
                , b.var1
                , b.var2
                , b.var3
                , b.var4
        from big_table as a
             , LIB.small_table as b
        where a.keyval1     ge  b.key1 
            and a.keyval1   lt  b.key2
            and a.keyval2   ge  b.key3 
            and a.keyval2   lt  b.key4
    ;
    quit;
```

So, when keyval1 in table a is greater or equal key1 in table b AND lower than key2 in table b,
AND keyval2 in table a is greater or equal key3 in table b AND lower than key4 in table b,
THAT is what I want to join on.

This makes it very complicated for me to write a hash join. I have no experience in this.
Sofar, I made this, but it is wrong:

```
    data output_table;
        drop rc;
        if _N_ = 1 then do;
        dcl hash cpohash(dataset: 'LIB.smalltable');
        cpohash.definekey('key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4');
        cpohash.definedata('var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4');
        cpohash.definedone();
        end;
        set big_table;
    
        rc=cpohash.find();
        do while (rc=0);
            if  key1 <=  keyval1   <  key2 
                and   key3   <=    keyval2   <=   key4 then output;
        rc = cpohash.find_next();
        end;
    
    run;
```

I can’t find any information on how to create a complex hash join like this. SQL isn’t good enough as one of the tables is exceptionally large (even after dividing it into 20 pieces).

Please, can you help me get the correct code or point out a website which explains such complex SAS hash joins?

Comment: What is wrong with using the SQL code?

Comment: As we don't have your data AND you don't share the error message, what are we supposed to do?

Comment: I cannot use the SQL code due to performance issues.

Comment: I see a lot of questions on here without the data and without the error code and they get answers. No need to be rude. If you know about hash joins, you can look at the code and see what's wrong, can't you? I just don't know anything about them and need help formulating the hash join...

Comment: @gjboor Code that produces an error should _always_ be posted with the error message - questions without are generally closed.  Questions also should include data when possible, obviously in this case you can't provide exact data, but you'll get much better answers with both.  There are lots of low quality questions on here, but particularly when making a "big" ask like this, as opposed to something very simple, you need to be providing as much as possible to get the best possible answer!

Comment: Provide more information about the types of values in those variables to get better suggestions.  What types of values are the two keys? The two pairs of upper/lower bounds?  Are they character strings? Integers? Floating point values?  How large is the small dataset? How wide are the upper/lower bound ranges? Do the ranges overlap at all?

Answer (score 0):

A hash join is not the right solution here, unfortunately, at least not the way you have it written.  A hash join requires an exact match; basically what's happening behind the scenes is the "key" is hashed (converted into a single string using a formula, similar to MD5 or SHA algorithms) and then SAS looks up the hash of the find-key in the stored table.  Because the hashing process makes totally different results for similar but not identical keys, you can't do any sort of math here - you have to look up specific values.  So in your case you are looking up the 4 keys, but they aren't actually exact matches in table A.

Depending on the actual numbers behind your data, though, it's possible there could be a solution that works.

If, for example, `key1` and `key2` aren't too far apart, and `key3` and `key4` aren't too far apart, then what you could possibly do is create a table C, that has *all of the possible exact matches from A*.

```
data c;
  set b;
  do keyval1 = key1 to key2;
    do keyval2 = key3 to key4;
       output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Something like that.  This is possibly *really big*, so please think about this before doing it.  But if it's not *too* big, then you now have a table C that contains all of the values you're looking for.  Then, you can do a straightforward hash table lookup.  You also could just do the SQL code, most likely, as there's a good chance SQL would choose a hash join anyway on the back end.

The other thing I would do, if this is not feasible, is look at indexes on table A that might make the query more feasible.  There are things you might be able to do to help SQL along, like if there are a bunch of rows in A that are before/less than *any* table B row, you could filter those out, or similarly rows that are after/greater than *any* table B row.